# Queries on Maven

Tags: java, maven

1) I created a java project using command
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=your.simple.java.gid -DartifactId=maventest
After project creation I checked pom.xml file and only depedecy I found is Junit.So why doe it download other libraries like asm, antlr, oro, xmlapis,Jdom etc.

2) After this I created a web project by command  mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp. In pom.xml Junit dependecy is available but in project there is no test folder. Why does not this  creates test folder?

3)If I go to .m2/repository folder there are multiple libary folder available. For example if I go inside asm directory .m2/repository/asm/asm/3.2 I found below files.

```
 a)asm-3.2.jar
 b)asm-3.2.jar.sha1
 c)asm-3.2.pom
 d)asm-3.2.pom.sha1
 e)_maven.repositories
```

I am not sure about .pom .sha1 and .repositories files. What are they for?

Comment: This is all just how Maven works, and the only answer is to read Maven documentation to understand it.

Comment: ASM is required by maven to create projects. Maven uses ASM as project assembler.

Comment: @Rupesh what about other libraries ?

Comment: refer to my comment below it may help...

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798724/asm-jar-why-my-java-project-has-a-dependency-on-this)

ASM is a bytecode manipulation framework (see this page for a nice introduction) and is used by many things performing... bytecode manipulation: frameworks using proxy generation and reflection (Spring, Hibernate, etc), mocking frameworks (EasyMock, JMock, etc), code analysis tools (PMD, Findbugs, etc). Actually, the ASM project maintains a list of users organized by category, check it out.